# can I override internal virtual methods

Tags: .net, cil

Of course, in a different assembly this is not possible in general. However, Microsoft states in its documentation for "[internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)":

> An internal virtual method can be overridden in some languages, such
>   as textual Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) using Ilasm.exe,
>   even though it cannot be overridden by using C#.

As I am desperately searching for a way to do exactly this I am wondering how this can actually be done. I was able to create an assembly that does exactly that by using ildasm/ilasm, but the runtime refuses to load it with an TypeLoadException, that tells me that it won't load classes that override internal methods. If it wasn't for that statement of Microsoft itself, I would give up this approach right now.
Are there maybe any security aspects that could be overcome and that would make the CLR more "relaxed"? Pl. note: the method I want to override is part of the .NET provided libraries (System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive).

*Why do I need this*:
I know that this method is not *meant* to be overridden and one should strive for a different design. However, I am quite confident, that my usecase does not have an alternative solution. I want to isolate parts of the control tree with catch clauses as to prevent faulty controls to destory the whole page. Unfortunately, MS does not provide any means to do so on official APIs (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139539/how-to-isolate-sub-controls-and-their-exceptions)!), and thus, I am hunting for such hacks now.

Thanks for any small hints.